# How to create Android app links using branch.io in Ionic 2/3 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding the implementation of some of the branch concepts for the **Ionic platform** Wrapper SDK .

I've generated short URLs using the SDK, but it seems to get **redirected** in the browser before the app is launched. **Link -> Browser -> App handoff**.

How do I avoid this redirection? I've enabled Android app link, added SHA 256 of certs and added all configs in config.xml as per SDK docs.

Is it possible to generate long links as using the "/a/ and the Branch Key" as in `https://bnc.lt/a/key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt?foo=bar&baz=456&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbranch.io%2F`

Something like `branchcordova://a/key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt?foo=bar&baz=456&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbranch.io%2F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use the **Android app link** (URI scheme), then the app would be open **directly**. But, it would be detected as a non-branch link and we might not get any analytics data or branch.io related features.

The redirection of **short and long URLs** seems to depend on the app which is opening the link. Some apps like Hangout app do the redirect thing.

If we are to open a branch link from inside our app, we could do the following to somehow skip the redirection.

```
const longLink = https://bnc.lt/a/key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt?foo=bar&baz=456;
window.open(longLink, '_system');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a configuration issue. Have you added your Link Domain on the `config.xml` file? You can find your Link Domain on the [Link Settings](https://dashboard.branch.io/link-settings) page.

```
<!-- sample config.xml -->
<widget id="com.eneff.branch.cordovatestbed" 
version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<!-- Branch -->
<plugin name="branch-cordova-sdk" spec="^2.5.0" />
<branch-config>
    <branch-key value="<YOUR LIVE KEY>" />
    <uri-scheme value="<YOUR URI SCHEME>" />
    <link-domain value="<YOUR LINK DOMAIN>" />
    <ios-team-release value="<YOUR TEAM ID>" />
</branch-config>
```

Long links can only be generated using your Link Domain.

Something like `branchcordova://a/key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt?foo=bar&baz=456&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbranch.io%2F` is incorrect.

Someting like `https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD?foo=bar&baz=456&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbranch.io%2F` is correct.

You should use `https://link.example.com` if you have a custom link domain configured.

More info on Long Links- https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#long-links

Comment: I have added the link domain and also URI scheme in config.xml.

Comment: When shared through hangouts/whatsapp, It's going through a redirection before opening the app.